# Reading file's content and writing to console

Tags: java

I have a program which reads contents from a file and prints it on the screen. But program prints every other line i.e., skips every other line.
package InputOutput;

```
import java.io.*;

public class CharacterFileReaderAndFileWriter{

    private BufferedReader br = null;

    private PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);


    /* Read from file and print to console */
    public void readFromFile() throws IOException{

        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Programming\\Class files\\practice\\src\\InputOutput\\test.txt"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        String s = null;
        do{
            s = br.readLine();
            pw.println(s);
        }
        while((s = br.readLine())!=null);

        br.close();
    }

    /* Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        CharacterFileReaderAndFileWriter cfr = new CharacterFileReaderAndFileWriter();

        cfr.readFromFile();
    }

}
```

Comment: Notice where you're calling `br.readLine()` and what you do with the result of each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you doing `s=br.readline()` twice.. you can have it like this.

```
String s = null;
 while((s = br.readLine())!=null)
{
   pw.println(s);
}
```

`readline()`reads a line everytime you call it, and goes to next one. so when you call it twice, obviously you are skipping a line. use this code, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You loop is wrong:

```
String s = null;
do{
    s = br.readLine();
    pw.println(s);
}
while((s = br.readLine())!=null);
```

Should be:

```
String s = null;
while((s = br.readLine())!=null) {
    pw.println(s);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your `do/while` loop to avoid calling `readline` twice and discarding every other result:

```
String s = null;
while((s = br.readLine())!=null) {
    pw.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the first line of your **do** loop. you are calling readLine() twice.

ie:

```
String s = null;
while((s = br.readLine())!=null) {
    pw.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your do-while loop if you want to go with do-while then kindly code it as follows.

```
String s = null;
do{        
    pw.println(s);
}
while((s = br.readLine())!=null);

br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change by:

```
  for(String s; (s = br.readLine()) != null;) {
        pw.println(s);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using br.readLine() two times.

```
String s = null;
    do{
        s = br.readLine();  //here it read first line 
        pw.println(s);      //here it prints first line    
    }
    while((s = br.readLine())!=null); //here s read second line
                                      //note that it is not printing that line

String s = null;
    do{
        s = br.readLine();  //this time it read third line
        pw.println(s);      //now it prints third line
    }
    while((s = br.readLine())!=null);   // this time it reads fourth line
```

So, this process will go on and your program will print lines one after another