# Exception Handling in Java/checked exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I am new to Java, and would appreciate any help in the following program, where I am trying to provide for a checked `exception`.

Her's example:

```
package book1;
import java.io.*;

public class CheckedException {

public static void main(String[] args) {
openFile("D:Java.txt");

} 

public static void openFile(String name)
{
try
{
FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream(name );
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
System.out.println("File Not Found!!");
}
}
}
```

The problem:

1. The ideal path to a text file on Windows should be D:\file.txt. But in this program, this syntax gives an error, indicating an incorrect escape syntax(\n,\t etc). Why is the compiler(I'm using Eclipse Kepler on Windows 8.1) treating the path file as an escape seq?
2. Even when I removed the \ from the notation(path D:java.txt), the program throws the file not found exception, and is subsequently caught which displays the file not found message.

Please help,

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java (and many other languages), you must escape the back slash with another backslash when coding String literals:

```
openFile("D:\\Java.txt"); // This is the string D:\Java.txt
```

but java understands forward slashes in file paths on operating systems that use backslashes for separators, so you could just do this:

```
openFile("D:/Java.txt");
```

---

To explain the error you're seeing, the string literal `"\:"` is an "escaped colon", which is *not* a valid java string escape sequence.

Comment: Thank You, but now even though the program did compile, it doesn't open the mentioned file. Instead the program quits with a "terminated" status just above the console window line. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2981518 that is because your program does nothing with the file. Do you want to show the contents of the file in the console or something?

Comment: @julian: yes, exactly.

Comment: @user2981518 then take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264803/reading-files-content-and-writing-to-console